# Add new property to react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-redux, setstate

I am trying to add a new property to the state "initialTags". However, I do not know how to do that. I have tried to loop through the object to set the new property, however it didnt work. Also, the setState it all in a same function, but since setState is async, I am unable to setState on the same state after my first setState statement.

**Initializing the state:**

```
this.setState({ initialTags: [...tempTarget] }, () => console.log("initTags == ", this.state.initialTags));
```

**Array of Object after setState:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "AQS",
        "projectId": "MTYzMDE1MzU3NjA3My10ZXN0MTA",
        "projectName": null,
        "isUserForAllProject": false
    },
    {
        "name": "ED",
        "projectId": null,
        "projectName": null,
        "isUserForAllProject": null
    },
    {
        "name": "PAID",
        "projectId": null,
        "projectName": null,
        "isUserForAllProject": null
    },
    {
        "name": "QS",
        "projectId": null,
        "projectName": null,
        "isUserForAllProject": null
    }
]
```

**The New property that needs to be added in the Object:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "AQS",
        "projectId": "MTYzMDE1MzU3NjA3My10ZXN0MTA",
        "projectName": null,
        "isUserForAllProject": false,
        "return": []

    },
    {
        "name": "ED",
        "projectId": null,
        "projectName": null,
        "isUserForAllProject": null,
        "return": []
    },
    {
        "name": "PAID",
        "projectId": null,
        "projectName": null,
        "isUserForAllProject": null,
        "return": []
    },
    {
        "name": "QS",
        "projectId": null,
        "projectName": null,
        "isUserForAllProject": null,
        "return": []
    }
]
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

```
this.setState({ initialTags: [...tempTarget.map(item => ({...item, returnVal: []}))] })
```

Comment: why don't you do it in one setSTate call?

Comment: "tempTarget" is from axios API call. However the api call does not contain the attribute "return". I am trying to add in the "return" property to be used in a component to track the onChange altogether.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. you can just edit the tempTarget whilte setting it to state

Comment: tempTarget returns all the objects that have matching ID between 2 list by using .map and .find.

Comment: let tempTarget = deptIds.map((id) => {
                    let item = this.state.departments.find((d) => d.id == id);
                    return item;
                  });

Comment: May i ask how will you do the setState to add the property before setting the state?

Comment: `this.setState({ initialTags: [...tempTarget.map(item => ({...item, returnVal: []}))] })`

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.setState((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        initialValues: prev.initialValues.map((item) => {
          return {
            ...item,
            returnValue: []
          };
        })
      };
    });
```

You shoudn't use `return` as it is a keyword.

Comment: The easiest way to solve your issue, is to run this code inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: hi, i just tested this out, but it adds the return at the back of all the objects. and index 0 now have all the values of the initialTags.

Comment: @Jingc Yes, as you literally showed in the example? Do you want it to behave differently?